# Issue using vimeo player in FF and IE - Loads flash player instead of using HTML5 player

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, froogaloop

I'm trying to dynamically load a vimeo  video in my app using their javascript Player API (https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api)

I've already loaded the froogaloop API js file, but when I add the player Iframe which I generated to the page and pass it to the API ($f($playeriframe))the flash player is loaded instead.

This only happens in IE and Firefox, in Chrome it works as it should.

For some reason as soon as I append the $playeriframe object to my page in FF and IE it is rendered and loads the flash player. In chrome the player only loads after the current batch of operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are missing the "allowfullscreen" attributes on the `<iframe>`. Make sure those are there and you should see the HTML player load in IE and Firefox.